# How can buttons, in a table, be set to the same size?

Tags: libgdx

I'm trying to make the UI more appealing by setting the main menu buttons to be the same size.

So the "Play" button is a bit bigger than the "Quit" button, and I tried :

```
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/myfont.ttf"));
    FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 22;
    mButtonSpacefont = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    generator.dispose();

    // Table for Buttons
    Table table=new Table();
    table.setSize(800, 480);

    // Button Skin
    Skin skin = new Skin();
    TextureAtlas buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("gfx/buttons.pack"));
    skin.addRegions(buttonAtlas);

    // BUTTON PLAY
    TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.font = mButtonSpacefont;
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("button_top");
    textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("button_bottom");
    final TextButton buttonPlay = new TextButton("Play", textButtonStyle);

    table.add(buttonPlay);
    table.row();

    // BUTTON QUIT
    final TextButton buttonQuit = new TextButton("Quit", textButtonStyle);
    buttonQuit.setWidth(buttonPlay.getWidth());// make the Quit button same size as Play button
    table.add(buttonQuit).padTop(50);
    table.row();
```

However, this doesn't work! The Quit button is still smaller than the Play button

Is there anything I did wrong ?

Comment: `Button extends Table`. So you can use `button.setSize(w, h)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To size all your buttons you could use the width method from the Cell class instead, like for example:

```
table.add(buttonPlay).width(100);
table.row();
table.add(buttonQuit).width(100);
```

then your buttons should end up having all the same width.

Comment: I guess that's a viable work-around. To use the width of the cell, I'd need to measure how wide the text is, add a few pixels for padding, and then set the width all the same.